# What is this err here?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, syntax-error

`const HttpError = require("../models/http-error");`

[image]

```js
//http-error.js
class HttpError extends Error {
    constructor(message, errorCode) {
        super(message); // Add a "message" property
        this.code = errorCode; // Adds a "code" property
    }
}

module.exports = HttpError;
```

What is the differences betwen **err** and **error** what is the job over here **err?**

Comment: `err` is whats thrown from `Place.findById`, whilst `error` is just a constant your defining which your not throwing and wont be in scope it should be thrown instead.. also the line abit further down if(!place) is actually throwing but your not caching it, presuming you have an outer error handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**err** is An optional identifier to hold an exception object for the associated catch-block. [MDN try...cactch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

`const error` is the object of your custom error handler